# Laravel displaying information in {% content %}

Tags: php, laravel, twig, octobercms

Have problem to display content block information

```
{% content 'structurated/'this.page.filename %}
```

This returns an error. If I remove `'structurated/'` `{% content this.page.filename %}` it is working and returning content block. But I need to return information from `structurated/` folder. How can I change code that would work ?

```
{% content 'structurated/'this.page.filename %}

ERROR:
Unexpected token "punctuation" of value "." ("operator" expected with value "=").
==========
{% content 'structurated/'.this.page.filename %}

An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("The content file '' is not found.").
==========
{% content 'structurated/'+this.page.filename %}

An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("The content file '0' is not found.").
```

Comment: Please, post the error. At first sight, it doesn't seam like you are concatenating your string and your variable correctly. Im not sure about the syntax but probably `'structurated/'.this.page.filename` or `'structurated/'+this.page.filename`

Comment: I update question with error.

Comment: What will happen if you explicit enter the filename? Like `{% content 'structurated/my_file' %}`

Comment: If I enter {% content 'structurated/advertising.htm' %} it's working.

Comment: OK, so it's definitely the concatenation. What's the templating syntax you're using?

Comment: Twig template engine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it.

```
{% content 'structurated/' ~ this.page.filename %}
```

It's right now not being concatenated correctly

Comment: Great to hear! :)